# Restrain Android MaterialTimePicker dialog to specific values of hours and minutes

Tags: android, datetimepicker, material-components-android

Is there a way to restrain the hours/minutes to specific values while a **MaterialTimePicker** is displayed in **Android**? In contrast to the **MaterialDatePicker** dialog there is no **CalendarConstraints** equivalent to impose some kind of input limit. I thought about allowing the user to press the ok button and rectify the input if the selected time is not in the desired range. Unfortunately, I have not found a way to set the hours/minutes after the `build()` method is called on the dialog. Could anyone think of an alternative?

Comment: FWIW: you're correct that time picker does NOT have constraints, this has been "requested" here: (but there are only cricket sounds heard from that...) https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2106

Comment: I think your best "bet" is to add a `addOnPositiveButtonClickListener` to the picker, evaluate if the selected time is within your "constrains" and if it's wrong, dismiss the picker and show the user the error... (a bit lame if you ask me).

Comment: I was thinking of something similar, if the time is not within the constraints, cancel dismissing the time picker and inform of the constraints on the picker title... Not very sexy either. But I don't know if it's possible to cancel the picker dismissal.

Comment: @DonMiguel did you find any answers or workaround?

Comment: @Red M Unfortunately no.